# Can't find flag for report if whole thread is confusing

Tags: feature-request, rejected-edits

If any user asks question in Stack Overflow and if a 2-3 developer adds some solution in Answers, and after trying this solution if he resolved this issue, then there is need to accept this.

But rather than accepting one of the working answers if he changes the whole question then no relation of this working answer and newly updated question.

I face this type of issue 2-3 times in this week, but right now I have one latest link.

[Check this Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40092852/app-not-working-after-new-activity)

And [This is answer of original Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40092852/app-not-working-after-new-activity/40092960#40092960) Read all comments

And [This is answer of updated question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40092852/app-not-working-after-new-activity/40094713#40094713)

This type of thread confused lots of developers

I can't get any flag for report this issue, what can I do?

Comment: A user changing the question (not uncommon after fixing the original problem and getting a new one) is not acceptable.  We rollback such an edit.  Next time do not encourage the user to do this.  A comment like "Please click the Ask Question button for your new problem" is usually good enough.

Comment: Regarding the main post, Instant Run was never the problem. The message the OP posted is not an error message, and mostly irrelevant to their issue. Granted, the OP stating that it's an error message is kinda misleading, but we should be able to distinguish, yeah? I mean, did you read the message? It's basically saying that Instant Run isn't even in play here. The OP editing to include the stack trace does not fundamentally change the question, and I disagree with Makoto's rollback. You made a bad assumption, but that doesn't mean the OP radically changed the question with their edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing question to something different that invalidates existing answers is not acceptable.

If you have enough reputation - roll back the edit and add comment that new question should be asked instead.

If rollback caused *any* complains/rolled back or you don't have enough reputation - flag with "other" and explain what happened like "user changed question to be completely different and invalidated answers.".

Comment: "Changing question to something different that invalidates existing answers is not acceptable." There's an exception to this and is when the original question wasn't acceptable in the first place... these users were jumping the gun when more effort was needed before answering.